# How to set a drawable over an image view

Tags: android, image, android-layout, gridview, background

I have a drawbale i want to place it in a gridView for each each image in this gridView.
My drawable is a like a square but filled at the edges. So when i set this drawable as a background for the image, the image will cover the background which i dont need.
I need this drawable to be in-front of the of the image not at the back.

My code look like this:
    enter code here

```
   public class ComponentAlbums extends LinearLayout 
   {
   public ClassImageLoader imageLoader;
   public ComponentAlbums(Activity activity,Context context,WallPaperHD_Album item)
{
    super(context);
    imageLoader = new ClassImageLoader(activity);

    setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams Params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(120, 120);
    ImageView imageView =  new ImageView(context);
    Params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    imageView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    //imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.frame_all_albums);//this line of     code iam using to set the drawable infront of the image.
```

any help please.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to reverse the background and the actual image.

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.frame_all_albums);
...
imageView.setBackgroundResource(actualImageBitmap);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: As Aswin said, the image content can overlap the backgroud.

Comment: i really need to fix that issue if someone can advice me with other options please

Comment: What are you seeing when you try this code? The frame should be on top the actual image. Do you see that?

Comment: what iam seeing is the imageview is covering the frame which is the drawable because the drawable is not a perfect square its a square but the edge below has an arc that covers the image view hope i explained it well

Comment: i need the imageview to be inside the drawable